# Specifying sensitive information in mocha tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm running mocha tests from the below script

```
"test:server": "mocha test/server/  --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/server/init_db.js  --recursive",
```

`init_db` has variables like the connection string to the local database. Since this is sensitive , i would like the connection string to be retrieved as an environment variable.

I considered setting it in such a way

```
"test:server": " DATABASE_URL = "*****" mocha test/server/  --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/server/init_db.js  --recursive"
```

But this wont solve the issue since everyone can see the connection string from `package.json`. For my development , i'm using `dotenv` and have a `.env` file from which node reads the connection string and sets it to `process.env.DATABASE_URL`. but this doesnt work for mocha because its not able to read the `.env` file specified.

Is there any other way i can set the sensitive info without putting `init_db` in my `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out , i can specify the info in my `.env` file and import it in mocha like the below

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

everything works now